# java xml cast Node to Element

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I know this was asked many times but I still cannot get it to work. I convert xml string to Document object and then parse it. Here is the code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
try
{
  builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
  Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( result ) ) );
  Node head = document.getFirstChild();
  if(head != null)
  {                  
    NodeList airportList = head.getChildNodes();      
    for(int i=0; i<airportList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = airportList.item(i);                        
    Element airportElem = (Element)n;
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I cast the Node object n to Element I get an exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.TextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element. When I check the node type of the Node object it says Node.TEXT_NODE. I believe it should be Node.ELEMENT_NODE. Am I right?

So how do I convert Node to Element, so I can do something like element.getAttribute("attrName").

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ArrayOfCity xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<City>
  <strName>Abu Dhabi</strName> 
  <strCode>AUH</strCode> 
</City>
<City>
  <strName>Amsterdam</strName> 
  <strCode>AMS</strCode> 
</City>
<City>
  <strName>Antalya</strName> 
  <strCode>AYT</strCode> 
</City>
<City>
  <strName>Bangkok</strName> 
  <strCode>BKK</strCode> 
</City>
</ArrayOfCity>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are we meant to know whether the first node should be an element or text, when you haven't shown us the document? I strongly suspect the parser is right though... I suspect you probably just want to skip non-element nodes.

Comment: I've added the xml. Node <City> should be an element, not a text. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but I think you'll find there's a text element (possibly just a line break) between `<ArrayOfCity>` and `<City>` - and between each `</City>` and `<City>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When I cast the Node object n to Element I get an exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.TextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element. When I check the node type of the Node object it says Node.TEXT_NODE. I believe it should be Node.ELEMENT_NODE. Am I right?

Probably not, the parser is probably right. It means that some of the nodes in what you're parsing are [**text nodes**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772). For example:

```
<foo>bar</foo>
```

In the above, we have a `foo` element containing a text node. (The text node contains the text `"bar"`.)

Similarly, consider:

```
<foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
```

If your XML document **literally** looks like the above, it contains a root element `foo` with these child nodes (in order):

- A text node with some whitespace in it
- A `bar` element
- A text node with some more whitespace in it

Note that the `bar` element is not the first child of `foo`. If it looked like this:

```
<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>
```

*then* the `bar` element would be the first child of `foo`.

Answer (score 20):

I think you need something like this:

```
NodeList airportList = head.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < airportList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = airportList.item(i);
    if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element elem = (Element) n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the package namespace of Element?

Answer (score 5):

you can also try to "protect" your casting

```
Node n = airportList.item(i);
if (n instanceof Element)
{                        
    Element airportElem = (Element)n;
    // ...
}
```

but as pointed by others, you have text node, those won't be casted by this method, be sure you don't need them of use the condition to have a different code to process them