# java DOM XML Parser Inner Element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am being able to parse the main elements of the xml by using XML DOM Parser, like for example I can get getElementsByTagName("id") , or getElementsByTagName("stock_number"), and so on, but I got to a problem since in the tag  I need to be able to return only the information of .

I have a XML in a file ***feed.xml*** like this:

```
<inventory>
    <item UnitID="1234" Record="0">
        <id>1234</id>
        <dealerid>455</dealerid>
        <stock_number>1600Xtreme</stock_number>
        <make>Nvidia</make>
        <noteshtml>This is some random info about the product1234.<br><br> 
         Buy with trust from a LQZ dealership.<br><br> Contact&nbsp;Dave at 
         Burnaby location - 604 123 4578.<br>
        </noteshtml>
        <images>
            <Image1 image="1" UnitID="1234">
                https://anydomain.com/photo54.jpg
            </Image1>
            <Image2 image="2" UnitID="1234">
                https://anydomain.com/photo22.jpg
            </Image2>
            <Image3 image="3" UnitID="1234">
                https://anydomain.com/photo32.jpg
            </Image3>
        </images>
    </item>
    <item UnitID="7854" Record="1">
        <id>7854</id>
        <dealerid>587</dealerid>
        <stock_number>12TMAX5500</stock_number>
        <make>Realtek</make>
        <noteshtml>This is some random info about the product 7854.<br><br> 
        Buy with trust from a LQZ dealership.<br><br> Contact&nbsp;Dave at 
        Burnaby location - 604 123 4578.<br>
        </noteshtml>
        <images>
            <Image1 image="1" UnitID="7854">
                https://anydomain.com/photo656.jpg
            </Image1>
            <Image2 image="2" UnitID="7854">
                https://anydomain.com/photo6565.jpg
            </Image2>
            <Image3 image="3" UnitID="7854">
                https://anydomain.com/photo908.jpg
            </Image3>
        </images>
    </item>
</inventory>
```

And this is in general my Java code for what I got so far:

```
File fXmlFile=new File("feed.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder=dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList=doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (int temp=0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
{
    Node nNode=nList.item(temp);
    Element eElement2=(Element)nNode;
    int search=1234;
    System.out.println("This is the value to search from my variable: " + search);
    int toTest=Integer.parseInt(eElement2.getAttribute("UnitID"));
    System.out.println("toTest is equal to: " + toTest);
    if (toTest == search)
    {
        System.out.println("stock Number: " + eElement2.getElementsByTagName("stock_number").item(0).getTextContent());
    }
}
```

My question is how to get now inside the images tag and print only the url of that image=1 identifier.

I have search a lot and researched how to use the DOM parser, i tried by creating a subElement of the Node but I get errors. 
I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get child in images tag, you can not call getChildNodes in the images tag directly, as there are some additional node, refer to [java xml cast Node to Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760502/java-xml-cast-node-to-element).
So try to get the child directly by getElementsByTagName.

```
File fXmlFile=new File("feed.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode;
    int search = 1234;
    System.out.println("This is the value to search from my variable: " + search);
    int toTest = Integer.parseInt(eElement2.getAttribute("UnitID"));
    System.out.println("toTest is equal to: " + toTest);
    if (toTest == search) {
        System.out.println(
                "stock Number: " + eElement2.getElementsByTagName("stock_number").item(0).getTextContent());
        Element images = (Element) eElement2.getElementsByTagName("images").item(0);
        Element image1Node = (Element) images.getElementsByTagName("Image1").item(0);
        Element image2Node = (Element) images.getElementsByTagName("Image2").item(0);
        Element image3Node = (Element) images.getElementsByTagName("Image3").item(0);
        if (image1Node.getAttribute("image").equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("image1Node id attribute is 1");
        }
        if (image2Node.getAttribute("image").equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("image2Node id attribute is 1");
        }
        if (image3Node.getAttribute("image").equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("image3Node id attribute is 1");
        }
    }
}
```