# Get the properties values of Node

Tags: java, xml, nodes, document, nodelist

I'm having some troubles to get the properies and their values of a `Node` from a `Document`, I'm executing a WebService that returns an XML, this WS can return two versions of an XML:

XML with ***"OK"*** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
<ENTRY1 CODE="00" MESSAGE="MESSAGE"/>
</data>
```

XML with ***"ERROR"*** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Root>
<Error DescErr="Error Description"/>
</Root>
```

Then, I'm able to detect the `<Error/>` `Node` in this case, but when I'm trying to get the `Node` `<data>` and their child `<ENTRY1/>` and the properties `CODE` and `MESSAGE` I'm getting and exception while I try to parse `Node` to `Element`:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element

This is my code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDom = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response.toString())));
if (xmlDom.hasChildNodes()) {
    NodeList listNodos = xmlDom.getElementsByTagName("Error");
    if (listNodos.getLength() > 0) {
            System.out.println("errors");
    } else {
       listNodos = xmlDom.getElementsByTagName("data");
       if (listNodos.getLength() > 0) {
          for (int x = 0; x < listNodos.getLength(); x++) {
              Node aux = listNodos.item(x);
              if (aux.hasChildNodes()) {
                 Node aux2 = aux.getFirstChild();
                 System.out.println(aux2.getNodeName());
                 Element element = (Element) aux2;//EXCEPTION THROWS HERE
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Can give me any suggeestion that what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a test and check all the children of your node `aux2`? Probably the requested element is not the first child.

Comment: @sanastasiadis in the line `System.out.println(aux2.getNodeName());` of the aux2 node prints `#text`

Comment: Make a loop to all children, and print their names, and you will find if/where the `<ENTRY1>` element is.

Comment: @sanastasiadis oh! it prints `#text ENTRY1 #text`, then Im trying to convert text into an `Element`, which is incorrect.

Comment: Check some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760502/java-xml-cast-node-to-element